# Impacts of Shutting down the Cassandra Seed Provider

Tags: cassandra, data-consistency

I have a cluster of 3 Cassandra nodes: Cassandra_1, Cassandra_2, Cassandra_3. In the cluster, Cassandra_1 is chosen as the seed provider. All Cassandra instances are in the same data center. Read/Write consistency level is set to ONE and the replication factor is set to 3.

My questions are:
1. Does the order of starting up the Cassandra instances matter? For example, if I startup Cassandra_2, Cassandra_3, and at the end Cassandra_1.

2. Does the seed provider have any effect on the data consistency among all nodes of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Seed Node should be up first. If the seed Node is up, after that you can start any node, it won't matter.
2. No, Seed Provider should not affect data consistency.
3. Always try to have more than one Seed node (recommended is 3 or more).